# Largest order of an element in $\mathbb{Z}_{128}^*$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Unlike $\mathbb{Z}_{144}^*$ we can break them into two group like $\mathbb{Z}_{16}^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{9}^*$. and take there largest order of element in group $\mathbb{Z}_{16}^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{9}^*$ and take the lcm of it. However, $\mathbb{Z}_{128}^*$ cannot break down into two different groups. So how do we find the largest order of element in $\mathbb{Z}_{128}^*$ with $\phi(2^7)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\ge 2$, $\Bbb Z_{2^n}^*$ is the direct product of a cyclic group of order $2$ generated by $-1$ and a cyclic group of order $2^{n-2}$ generated by $5$.

To see $5$ has order $2^{n-2}$ modulo $2^n$, one can inductively prove the
congruence
$$5^{2^k}\equiv1+2^{k+2}\pmod{2^{k+3}}.$$

Comment: Did you get the 5 from $2^{7 - 2}$ ? And what is $k$ for the congruence above?

Comment: $k$ is a natural number

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hey, I knew that the largest order of element in the group is 32. But how do we find 32 with the answer above?

Comment: It’s the order of $5$ mod $2^n$, i.e., $2^{n-2}$; in your example, $n=7$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So basically by the theorem provided. We can say that the largest order is $2^{7 - 2} = 32$? Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct